# rotate image after find chess corners

Tags: android, opencv

I'm using opencv in android application

```
Size chessboardSize = new Size(3,3);
MatOfPoint2f corners = new MatOfPoint2f();
Mat frame= inputFrame.gray().clone();
boolean result = Calib3d.findChessboardCorners(
    frame, 
    chessboardSize, 
    corners, 
    Calib3d.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK
);
Calib3d.drawChessboardCorners(frame, chessboardSize, corners, result);
```

after finding chessboard corners on image I get this
[image]
how to rotate the image to make it right?
I need result like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the chess corners, you need to find the homography with [`cv::findHomography()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=homography#findhomography) relating the chess corners to a specified axis aligned square. Once you have the homography you can [`cv::warpPerspective()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) the image to get the result you want.